# Unity | The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, google-speech-api

I have `using Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1;` in a C# script and I have installed Google SDK on my PC.

Unity gives this compile error saying

> Assets\recognition.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any clues on how to get through this ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you have the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.TextToSpeech.V1/) added to your project?

Comment: no , btw I'm editing scripts directly and not using VS , should I  jump on VS and add NuGet ?

Comment: Note that C# != UnityScript. UnityScript is a Javascript derivative created for Unity.

Comment: @elyeschine Using an IDE such as VS is generally considered a positive move, but its not required per se.